# Distinguish a 32bit from a 64bit PE object file generated by cl.exe (Visual Studio C++)

Tags: c++, windows, executable, msys2, cl

Given two PE object files from `cl.exe`, one 32bit and one 64bit, how can I tell one from the other **without** resorting to unix utilities, and preferably on the commandline (cmd.exe or powershell)?

```
C:\> "...\VC\bin\cl.exe" -c test.c           -Fotest32.obj
C:\> "...\VC\bin\x86_amd64\cl.exe" -c test.c -Fotest64.obj
```

If I install [msys2](https://msys2.github.io/)  the `file` utility can sortof make sense of it:

```
$ file test*.obj
test32.obj: Intel 80386 COFF object file, not stripped, 3 sections, [...]
test64.obj: data
```

`file --version` is 5.28, but the newer 5.25 does not do any better. msys2 does not offer an `objdump.exe`, but when copied to Linux it could properly tell these two files apart:

```
$ objdump -a test64.obj
test64.obj:     file format pe-x86-64
$ objdump -a test32.obj
test32.obj:     file format pe-i386
```

Something which does better than `file` and is available via msys2's pacman might also be interesting.

Comment: The Microsoft tool is `dumpbin`.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: http://superuser.com/q/358434/29943

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most straight forward way is to use Microsoft's [DUMPBIN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1h23y6c.aspx) tool, passing the [/HEADERS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ha900t8.aspx) option, e.g.

```
dumpbin /HEADERS cl.exe | findstr "machine"
```

This produces the following output for a 64-bit image

```
            8664 machine (x64)
```

or the following for a 32-bit image

```
             14C machine (x86)
                   32 bit word machine
```